# How to cancel a Ctrl-A in screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

Sometimes when I'm using my screen session I prematurely type Ctrl-A and then decide I want to remain in the current window and type something in the terminal, but anything I type next will be interpreted by screen and not sent to the Terminal. I try to "cancel" the Ctrl-A with Esc but that's used for copy mode, so I end up doing something I don't want.

Is there anyway to cancel a Ctrl-A command in screen?

Comment: How about `i` which just prints some info in the status bar (but don't hit accidently the `k` ;) )? Or like you did `ESC`, but twice, first one activates, second one immediately aborts copy mode...

Answer (score 0):

Use any arrow key, up down left or right

↑↓←→